# New record doesn't gets saved in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want create and save new user on a data base from "new" view, but new record don't save in data base.But try make this from the console and all it works, how fix?

this is my Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name)
  end
end
```

this is log from the console, as you can see transaction runs

```
2.1.2 :001 > user = User.new(name:"mike", email:"qwerty123@gmail.com", password:"123456", password_confirmation:"123456")
 => #<User id: nil, name: "mike", email: "qwerty123@gmail.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$uxFvZ4/T3rb2rQlEBAKkWuo13CUZsaBNG.DD5DPpHlI..."> 
2.1.2 :002 > user.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" = 'mike' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('qwerty123@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-13 10:08:01.402404"], ["email", "qwerty123@gmail.com"], ["name", "mike"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$uxFvZ4/T3rb2rQlEBAKkWuo13CUZsaBNG.DD5DPpHlI3WjzUhl3.u"], ["updated_at", "2014-11-13 10:08:01.402404"]]
   (204.8ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

which does not work?
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, it seems you have to permit `password` and `password_confirmation` in your controller. Try changing `user_params` method to look like this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

**Edit**. Also, please paste an excerpt from your web server log to unveil what happens when you submit the form.

Comment: wait a 5 minute :)   I have a small carma

Answer (score 0):

try to change `save` for `save!` and you may get a better output displaying what is missing or malformed:

```
def create
    [...]
    @user.save!
    [...]
end
```

Comment: forgot to mention: you can use the `better_errors` gem to get even more out of the error messages in case you don't use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read about permitting params in rails 4 and the validations.

If you are validating your User model on attributes (name, email,password) no record will be saved without at least these attributes.

Moreover, Rails require permitting the expected params from each form for security reasons that will stop anybody from adding new fields and submit them with your form.

**Take a look** at what is [Mass assignment in rails](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mass-assignment-rails-and-you--net-31695) and the difference between rails 3 and 4 in that matter.

Also take a look at [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) and [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) to know why record did not successfully saved.

ex::

```
user = User.new(name: "AnyName")
user.save
puts user.errors.messages -->> This will print email cannot be blank in your server if you are validating the presence of the email attribute.
```